# Seeking source for grib data download?

Tags: data, weather, grib, grib-2

I am trying to integrate wind maps into an existing map and I would like to download the latest wind data for a local area like zyGrib does and then attach it into the map.

I am aware that there are sources where I could get this data for free but I have been unsuccessful in finding a source. Could someone point me to a free service that I could use to download the GRIB data preferably in bzipped format if possible.

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then I think you would be better to ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.